# Maven Central is which exactly repository?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

Are https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central and    [http://central.maven.org/maven2/](https://web.archive.org/web/20181116044959/http://central.maven.org/maven2/) the same maven repository (called *Maven Central*)?

Also there is https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ which also calles itself a Central Repository.

I use `mvnrepository.com` as I find it more convenient, but many referencies to Maven Central in Internet lead to http://central.maven.org

Besides both sites above are for Maven2, right?

What are the analogues for Maven3?

Besides is Maven3 widely used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, `mvnrepository` is just a search site that is not maintained by the maven people directly. It's a search site as I see it. It has been around for a while. Since it contains multiple repository source to search in and lets you select which one you work with its pretty transparent and I don't see any harm there.

If you execute `mvn help:effective-settings` you should be able to determine what repositories are used, in case some changes where made. The current central default in maven seems to be https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ - the official search interface being https://search.maven.org/

You can also look into the maven [sources of the pom](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-model-builder/src/main/resources/org/apache/maven/model/pom-4.0.0.xml) what config you running on.

The /maven2/ part in the Uri only means what repository format is used within. This has not changed for maven 3 (it was different for maven 1). So it's the correct and current one today, there is no maven 3 repository format. Everything new could be added to the maven 2 format (for example some search index files or checksum files).